# Change css property in chain - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

I'm using MooTools 1.4.5 and I want to change cursor before calling function that takes some time and after finished same function set cursor to default. I was not successful.

After that I made simple example to change background color via plain JavaScript (no jQuery or MooTools plugin) and again I was not successful.

Here is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
        setTimeout(function () {  }, 1250);
        document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
    //-->    
    </script>
</html>
```

First at all I set background color to red, and after delay to yellow. I assumed that the background color will bi set to red and after delay to yellow. It doesn't work. When page is loaded background color is yellow (last line). If I insert alert function in a middle of lines where sets background color everything works fine (background color is red, click to message box, background color is yellow).
Why it works so? Only last changing style is affected. I need something like that to change pointer before calling function that takes 10 seconds and setting cursor to default value after function is done.

Comment: `setTimeout()` doesn't pause the execution, but only delays the code inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) doesn't mean "wait". It calls the function you give it sometime later. The flow of execution continues immediately:

```
document.body.style.background = 'red';
setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
}, 1250);
```

As such, this works too:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow';
}, 1250);
document.body.style.background = 'red';
```

---

For the case of a cursor, just replace `.background = 'red'` with `.cursor = 'wait'` and `.background = 'yellow'` with `.cursor = 'default'`.

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
setTimeout(function() {
    doSomethingExpensive();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `setTimeout()` is a callback function, which will be called after the delay, you should use this kind of code :

```js
document.body.style.background = 'red';
document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
setTimeout(function(){ 
   document.body.style.background = 'yellow'; 
   document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
}, 1250);
```

```css
body { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum.
```

See more about setTimeout [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: It works! But how to change cursor? 
Pseudocode:
this.setCursor("wait");
function(){//something};
this.setCursotr("default");

where execution of function takes 10 seconds.

Comment: For the cursor, use `document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';`

Comment: I try set to wait, but always last order is affected. Always is default althoug function takes 10 seconds.

Comment: _"I try set to wait, but always last order is affected."_ - I have no idea what you mean

Comment: Me neither. For me, this code do what you're searching for : http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/N7eqD/1/

Comment: Before function is called I want to set cursor to wait. After that I calll function that takes 10 seconds and finally set cursor to normal. Code works fine, function is called, but cursor (or background color, whatever) allways takes last changes (in example last line line of code):

this.setCursor("wait");
function(){ //something that takes 10 seconds};
this.setCursor("default");

Comment: One precision : your cursor will be on `wait` only if your mouse is over the `body`

Comment: Here is my original code:
                    $('treeView_divAroundUl').setStyle('background-color', 'red');                                            
                    var contentID = "Content_" + value.ID;

                    ExpandNode.attempt(contentID);
                    $('treeView_divAroundUl').setStyle('background-color', 'red');

Comment: Huuum... Here I see double `background-color: red`, and not a single `setTimeout`. Doesn't really looks like the problem we are on.

Comment: I don't have setTimeout. I used it to simulate some delay but I was wrong.

Comment: Sorry:
                    $('treeView_divAroundUl').setStyle('background-color', 'red');                                            
                    var contentID = "Content_" + value.ID;

                    ExpandNode.attempt(contentID);
                    $('treeView_divAroundUl').setStyle('background-color', 'yellow');

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use ExpandNode (never used/seen), but I guess this call is asynchronous, and the next line is directly executed. Try to find/generate an event which will be dispatched at the end of your expand, and when you catch it, via a listener, execute your last line.

Comment: ExpandNode is my/custom function.

Comment: Here is a jQuery example were I set the background to red, and use a listener to see if my last div is created before change the background to yellow : http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/VNZ8y/1/

Comment: OK. Try this example (some modification of your code) http://jsfiddle.net/SilverDeveloper/kt6xD/.  Finally, my question is: why at the begining of executon code background color is not red (I don't see in the browser!). I expected red background color, new div's inserted in for loop, and finally yellow background color. Only what I see is background color yellow and new div's.

Comment: That's because your JS script is fully executed before display the result. In my example, I moved the yellow set in a listener.

Comment: Ok. It's my conclusion too :) Do you have some link with explanation?

Comment: That's something basic in Javascript, that's why we used to put scripts on the end of `body` and/or wait the document.ready to launch them : http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch12_03.htm